# How to delete a file?

Tags: java, file

I used the following code to delete the text file. But it won't delete the file, which still exists.

```
File delfile=new File("SDS_DID.txt");
delfile.delete();
```

How to delete a file?

Comment: Did you make sure it was the right path? Is the file write protected?

Comment: can you get the return value of the delete function and see if it returns true

Comment: Have you checked whether your path is correct (`delfile.exists()`)? Also, always check the return value of `delete()`. It won't show you why it failed but whether it failed. Which is not much but better than nothing.

Comment: its obvious from the code that he didnt create a protected file.  i would be looking for an exception.

Comment: you can also check if you have write permissions by calling delfile.canWrite()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.gc(); // close any streams first

  String fileName = "SDS_DID.txt";
// A File object to represent the filename
File f = new File(fileName);

// Make sure the file or directory exists and isn't write protected
if (!f.exists())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "Delete: no such file or directory: " + fileName);

if (!f.canWrite())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: write protected: "
      + fileName);


// Attempt to delete it
boolean success = f.delete();

if (!success)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: deletion failed");
```

Comment: @ DSW: It prints true. But still the file exists. For your clarification, I run a exe through code, which will create that SDS_DID.txt file. And I access that file, after finishing access it i need to delete this file.

Comment: check write permissions by `canWrite()`

Comment: I used your updated code. still no deletion occur.. no exceptions.

Comment: have you try with System.gc() as well?

Answer (score 2):

1. Try using the absolute path to the file
2. Make sure you have write permission on the file
3. file.delete() returns a boolean value signifying whether it succeeded. Check that value.

Comment: File supports a file name without a path.  There is no reason to think that #1 will solve this.

Comment: @django, File supporting a partial path doesn't mean author understands the use of a partial path. Could easily have something in the wrong place.

Comment: @djangofan: If SDS_DID.txt doesn't exist in the same directory that the application is being run in, then it's entirely possible that the file isn't being found. SDS_DID.txt might exist anywhere on the drive.

Comment: @Jack Sparrow: check the return value on file.Exists().

Answer (score 1):

The most common problem is the file is not found.
Make sure the file already exists.

```
String fileName = "SDS_DID.txt";
// A File object to represent the filename
File f = new File(fileName);
if (!f.exists) {
JOptionPane.showErrorDialog (null , filename + " is not found.");
}
```

You can't just pick up a file anywhere on the hard drive, you have to tell where it actually is.